# Utility to extract variables from an expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm looking for a utility that would take an expression and extract all variables in that expression. 
Following five examples cover pretty much all of my variable patterns

`a,Subscript[a,....],Subscript[a,...][...],a[...],a[...][...]`

Here are two test cases.

```
expr1 = -Log[Subscript[\[Mu], 2][]] Subscript[\[Mu], 2][] - 
   Log[Subscript[\[Mu], 2][2]] Subscript[\[Mu], 2][2] + 
   Log[Subscript[\[Beta], 1, 2][]] Subscript[\[Beta], 1, 2][] + 
   Log[2] Subscript[\[Beta], 1, 2][1] + 
   Log[Subscript[\[Beta], 1, 2][1]] Subscript[\[Beta], 1, 2][1] + 
   Log[2] Subscript[\[Beta], 1, 2][2] + 
   Log[Subscript[\[Beta], 1, 2][2]] Subscript[\[Beta], 1, 2][2] + 
   Log[Subscript[\[Beta], 2, 3][]] Subscript[\[Beta], 2, 3][] + 
   Log[Subscript[\[Beta], 2, 3][2]] Subscript[\[Beta], 2, 3][2] + 
   Log[2] Subscript[\[Beta], 2, 3][3] + 
   Log[Subscript[\[Beta], 2, 3][3]] Subscript[\[Beta], 2, 3][3];

expr2 = Log[\[Beta][{1, 2}][{}]] \[Beta][{1, 2}][{}] + 
  Log[2] \[Beta][{1, 2}][{1}] + 
  Log[\[Beta][{1, 2}][{1}]] \[Beta][{1, 2}][{1}] + 
  Log[2] \[Beta][{1, 2}][{2}] + 
  Log[\[Beta][{1, 2}][{2}]] \[Beta][{1, 2}][{2}] + 
  Log[\[Beta][{2, 3}][{}]] \[Beta][{2, 3}][{}] + 
  Log[\[Beta][{2, 3}][{2}]] \[Beta][{2, 3}][{2}] + 
  Log[2] \[Beta][{2, 3}][{3}] + 
  Log[\[Beta][{2, 3}][{3}]] \[Beta][{2, 3}][{3}] - 
  Log[\[Mu][{2}][{}]] \[Mu][{2}][{}] - 
  Log[\[Mu][{2}][{2}]] \[Mu][{2}][{2}]

On[Assert];
Assert[Union@extractVariables@expr1 === Union[Variables[expr1][[9 ;;]]]]
Assert[Union@extractVariables@expr2 === Union[Variables[expr2][[9 ;;]]]]
```

Here's MrWizard's solution

```
extractVariables[formula_] := (
   pat = _Symbol[___][___] | Subscript[_Symbol, __][___] | Subscript[_Symbol, __] | _Symbol;
   Union@Cases[formula, pat, -1]
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is some code I use to get at "variables" in various types of expression (lists, equations, inequalities, and inside numeric functions).

```
headlist = {Or, And, Equal, Unequal, Less, LessEqual, Greater, 
   GreaterEqual, Inequality};

getAllVariables[f_?NumericQ] := Sequence[]
getAllVariables[{}] := Sequence[]
getAllVariables[t_] /; MemberQ[headlist, t] := Sequence[]

getAllVariables[ll_List] := 
 Flatten[Union[Map[getAllVariables[#] &, ll]]]

getAllVariables[Derivative[n_Integer][f_][arg__]] := 
 getAllVariables[{arg}]

getAllVariables[f_Symbol[arg__]] := 
 Module[{fvars}, 
  If[MemberQ[Attributes[f], NumericFunction] || MemberQ[headlist, f], 
   fvars = getAllVariables[{arg}],(*else*)fvars = f[arg]];
  fvars]

getAllVariables[other_] := other
```

One example from provided tests:

In[36]:= getAllVariables[expr2]

Out[36]= {[Beta][{1, 2}][{}], [Beta][{1, 2}][{1}], [Beta][{1, 
    2}][{2}], [Beta][{2, 3}][{}], [Beta][{2, 3}][{2}], [Beta][{2, 
    3}][{3}], [Mu][{2}][{}], [Mu][{2}][{2}]}

This could be extended to handle a larger class of expressions, e.g. Boolean, math with dummy variables (e.g. Sum or Integrate), some programmatic constructs. Expect thorny issue to appear.

Anecdote: Way back in the last millenium someone in the Kernel Dept scheduled a meeting to discuss the issue of "What is a variable?" This was within the setting of Mathematica, not general math or CS. All the same, it is an elusive thing to pin down because different functions seem to have different requirements for such entities. My own take on it was to reply that I would be sick that day (of the intended meeting). I do not recall if I was asked how I knew that in advance...

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: Thanks. I added a small edit in the answer to make it pass my test cases

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau - In regard to your anecdote, this is one of the main stumbling blocks I wrestle with frequently in MMA. I wish there were some guidance on how to define general models, where variables can be either endogenous or exogenous. Ex: What is the 'best' approach to declaring a variable as an exogenous parameter? Using Attribute Constant? Or just cram everything into Assumptions (globally or locally) and then relying on Simplify, etc.? The Attribute-based approach is easy, but incomplete---as I long to also then enforce Attributes related to type and range---a no go in MMA.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious (but presumably incorrect) approach would be:

```
pat = _Symbol[___][___] | Subscript[_Symbol, __][___] |  Subscript[_Symbol, __] | _Symbol;

Cases[expr1, pat, -1]
Cases[expr2, pat, -1]
```

But frankly I don't understand you question well enough to know where this goes wrong.

---

If that actually works for you, then I recommend:

```
extractVariables[formula_] := 
  With[{pat = _Symbol[___][___] | Subscript[_Symbol, __][___] | Subscript[_Symbol, __] | _Symbol},
    Union@Cases[formula, pat, -1]
  ]
```

Comment: @Yaroslav, see my edit.  It keeps `pat` local rather than open to `Global`.